# SQL query using substring to separate data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this and I need to separate them based on 
account=10825 and instance id =0

I have tried this using substring with charindex, but need to improve for further queries as it was not in the same format every time.

data:
1:

```
Month=12&Year=2015&Accounts=[10825].[44].[1]&Users=[RL665480003].[44]&Culture=en-US&DMSWebService=http%3A%2F%2Fausydapi01.recall.com%2Fdmswebservice%2Fdmswebservice.svc&OLTAccountID=0&OLTInstanceID=0&DaystoDestroy=90&LastLoadDate=12%2F30%2F2015 00%3A00%3A00&connectionString=Data Source%3Damatldb09%3BInitial Catalog%3DLocalizationDB%3BUser ID%3Dlocalization%3BPassword%3Dr3call%3B&ResourceType=BICustomerPortal&LastLoadDateDW=12%2F31%2F2015 12%3A00%3A00 AM&Period=12%2F30%2F2015 00%3A00%3A00
```

2:

```
Culture=en-US&Month=12&Year=2015&Accounts=[2784].[6].[1]&Users=[RL042671018].[6]&DMSWebService=http%3A%2F%2Fruss-app.recall.com%2Fdmswebservice%2Fdmswebservice.svc&OLTAccountID=0&OLTInstanceID=0&DaystoDestroy=90&ResourceType=BICustomerPortal&connectionString=Data Source%3Damatldb09%3BInitial Catalog%3DLocalizationDB%3BUser ID%3Dlocalization%3BPassword%3Dr3call%3B
```

Comment: What data are you trying to extract?

Comment: from the data 1 i need to get only accounts = 10825  and from data 2 i need account=2784

Comment: You should show exactly what you need to extract.  You didn't answer my question :-(

Comment: Do you really have to do this in SQL? The world has moved on a little bit. You've got a custom data format in your query string (the square brackets and dots), but you should really be looking to do this with model-binding, in a web framework like mvc, web api or Nancy, if we're talking dot net.

Answer (score 0):

What you've got there looks like a querystring from a browser (or a set of posted variables). So it will vary in length as you say, and also maybe the ordering and quantity of the variables could potentially change too.

So the only reliable way I can think of to do this is to effectively de-serialize the querystring. Since you're using SQL, we'll do it into a temp table. You can use the special characters used in querystrings: "&" (to separate parameters) and "=" (to separate the parameter name from the value) as markers to do this.

```
DECLARE @data nvarchar(MAX)
-- using your first data sample as an example:
SET @data = 'Month=12&Year=2015&Accounts=[10825].[44].[1]&Users=[RL665480003].[44]&Culture=en-US&DMSWebService=http%3A%2F%2Fausydapi01.recall.com%2Fdmswebservice%2Fdmswebservice.svc&OLTAccountID=0&OLTInstanceID=0&DaystoDestroy=90&LastLoadDate=12%2F30%2F2015 00%3A00%3A00&connectionString=Data Source%3Damatldb09%3BInitial Catalog%3DLocalizationDB%3BUser ID%3Dlocalization%3BPassword%3Dr3call%3B&ResourceType=BICustomerPortal&LastLoadDateDW=12%2F31%2F2015 12%3A00%3A00 AM&Period=12%2F30%2F2015 00%3A00%3A00'

DECLARE @workingtable TABLE
(
    ID [int] IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ItemID [nvarchar](2000),
    ItemValue [nvarchar](2000)
)

DECLARE @Item nvarchar(4000)
        ,@ItemID [nvarchar](2000)
        ,@ItemValue [nvarchar](2000)
        ,@pos int
        ,@count int
        ,@row int
        ,@delimiter1 varchar(1)
        ,@delimiter2 varchar(1);

SET @delimiter1 = '&';
SET @delimiter2 = '='
SET @data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@data)) + @delimiter1
SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter1, @data, 1)
SET @count = 0;
SET @row = 0;

IF REPLACE(@data, @delimiter1, '') <> '' -- make sure there are actually any delimited items in the list
BEGIN
    WHILE @pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @count = @count + 1
        SET @Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@data, @pos - 1))) -- get the querystring parameter and its value
        SET @ItemID = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@Item, CHARINDEX(@delimiter2, @Item) -1))) -- now extract the parameter value
        SET @ItemValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(@Item, LEN(@Item) - CHARINDEX(@delimiter2, @Item)))) -- now extract the parameter name
        INSERT INTO @workingtable ([ItemID], [ItemValue]) VALUES (@ItemID, @ItemValue) -- store in working table

        SET @data = RIGHT(@data, LEN(@data) - @pos) -- remove the item we just extracted from the list
        SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter1, @data, 1) -- reset the position to point to the next delimiter
    END
END

SELECT ItemID, ItemValue FROM @workingtable
```

Once you've got that, you can find the specific value you want very easily. You mentioned getting the first part of the "Accounts" field. So you could get the whole Accounts field like this:

```
    SELECT ItemValue FROM @workingtable WHERE [ItemID] = 'Accounts'
```

or find the specific part like this:

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING(ItemValue, CHARINDEX('[', [ItemValue]) + 1, CHARINDEX(']', [ItemValue]) - 2) FROM @workingtable WHERE [ItemID] = 'Accounts'
```

Obviously if you want this functionality to be easily re-usable I suggest you encapsulate it in a function or procedure.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the following that has the limitation that the len of the accountid is not more than 100 chars.

```
declare @str varchar(1000)
set @str='Month=12&Year=2015&Users=[RL665480003].[44]&Culture=en-US&DMSWebService=http%3A%2F%2Fausydapi01.recall.com%2Fdmswebservice%2Fdmswebservice.svc&OLTAccountID=0&OLTInstanceID=0&DaystoDestroy=90&LastLoadDate=12%2F30%2F2015 00%3A00%3A00&connectionString=Data Source%3Damatldb09%3BInitial Catalog%3DLocalizationDB%3BUser ID%3Dlocalization%3BPassword%3Dr3call%3B&ResourceType=BICustomerPortal&LastLoadDateDW=12%2F31%2F2015 12%3A00%3A00 AM&Period=12%2F30%2F2015 00%3A00%3A00&Accounts=[10825].[44].[1]'

select SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@str,  patindex('%Accounts=[[]%', @str) + len('Accounts=[') ,  100) , 0 ,  patindex('%]%', SUBSTRING(@str, patindex('%Accounts=[[]%', @str) + len('Accounts=[') ,  100)) )
```